# BigDecimal recebe o valor de uma string

Tags: java

Estou com a seguinte dúvida, de como realizar a soma de um `BigDecimal` com uma `String`.

```
String a = "8";
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(2);
```

Seria algo parecido com isto? `b.add(a);`

Obs: preciso que a lógica seja esta, apenas preciso saber como atribuir o valor de um `BigDecimal` de uma variável `String`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String a = "8";
BigDecimal a2 = new BigDecimal(a);
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(2);
BigDecimal c = b.add(a2);
```

Comment: Não funciona, ao dar o valor da variavel a  ao BigDecimal a2 ele dá erro

Comment: @WerikyAlphazero Qual erro?

Comment: Fui eu que errei amigo, desculpe. Muito obrigado